# How i can change IOS Xcode Project Location And Full Path ? Its showing wrong Path and location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, path, location

[image]Hi in my IOS Xcode project showing wrong Location and Full Path because of that i couldnt able to use that copied project in any other mac.If i use In other mac its showing red color file. Can anyone tell solution quickly.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You copy folder of project or only file?

Comment: Any picture for more details?

Comment: @sourleangchhean i attached screenshot in that screen shot it was showing project path in repositories but mine is on desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution for my issue.. i recreated entire project now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

I am taking two paths wrong path and correct path.

case 1. If file also exist in correct path : first open the project and remove reference of that file and then drag the file from correct path in opened project.

case 2. If file do not exist in correct path : copy file from wrong path and past in correct path and then open the project and remove reference of that file and then drag the file from correct path in opened project.

case 3. if path of all files is incorrect then if you are using pods then perform above action for "xcworkspace" other wise perform above action for "xcodeproj"

Comment: some files showing correct path some files showing wrong path and yes i am using pods

Comment: First of all take the backup.

open project in xcode, 

Check path of "xcworkspace" if this is wrong then drag the "xcworkspace" file from correct path and drop in xcode project bundle. If still some files are showing wrong path then you have to repeat same process for those files as well.                                                      
       
if path of xcworkspace is correct then drag file of wrong path from correct path in Xcode bundle.

Comment: i tried its not working can you explain briefly that procedure

Comment: did you changed the name of project